# Present UIImagePickerController crashes

Tags: ios, crash, uiimagepickercontroller

It's even easy to reproduce, if you create a new project (Single view application) and add:

```
// Swift
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    present(UIImagePickerController(), animated: true)
}
```

or

```
// Objective-C
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self presentViewController:[UIImagePickerController new] animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

It crashes either way on iPhone 7 simulator.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: What error it shows in console?

Comment: None. It crashes out of the main thread and it shows in the main window `->  0x1088f4f06 <+10>: jae    0x1088f4f10               ; <+20>` the line that crashed.

Comment: if you are running with ios10 you should have updated info.plist file for permission to open camera see this http://useyourloaf.com/blog/privacy-settings-in-ios-10/

Comment: Yeah... I just saw those logs on a new project that I didn't have the 1 Billion logs disabled... why the F*** Apple does these things?